# how to scale a value from 0-1 to 0-5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have these facts:

the user (X) rates the item (I) by (4/5)

the item (II) is 0.5 similar to item (I), 0.5 means 50% (the scale is from 0 to 1)

then I can say (according to my business model) that the user X likes the item (II) by:

4/5 * 0.5 (is that right) ?

if yes, my problem is that the result will be between 0 and 1, how can I scale it to from 0 to 5 (like a 5-start model)

Comment: Why not just $0.5 \times 4 = 2$ (out of $5$) for the second item?

Comment: @EthanBolker i don't know if that is correct mathematically, do you think?

Comment: It's "mathematically correct" since it will give consistent answers if you use it in several places. It's up to you to decide if it provides sensible answers in  your business model.

Comment: @EthanBolker okay I'm looking for something mathematically correct, maybe I didn't describe good, but what i am looking for is: if i know that you like an item by (4/5) states and we have another similar items, how much can we *predicate* that you will like that time. did you get me please?

Comment: @EthanBolker okay i got u thanks

Comment: Whether this is a good way to predict how much you will like a similar item is not a mathematical question, it's a psychology question.

Answer (score 0):

To rescale from 0-1 to 0-5 you just need to multiply by 5.

Reading carefully your question and comments, you are really looking into getting a weight of a rating according to the percentage of similarity from one product to another.  Ethan Bolker is correct, you just multiply the 100% known product rating (4/5) and the % similarity (0.5) and you get (2/5).

The problem with this is that you assume that 50% of similarity brings 50% of prediction... you have 50% more to take into account to get the whole rating.  This would require weighting the different factors customers like, lets say:

Item (I) has $\frac{4}{5}$ rating and an Item (II) has $\frac{3}{5}$ rating.

What is the predictability of rating my new product III which has 50% Item (I) and 50% Item (II)?
Predicted rating of Item (III) is $\frac{4}{5}*0.5+\frac{3}{5}*0.5=\frac{3.5}{5}$

If percentages were different: lets say (III) gets 60% from Item (I) and 40% from Item (II):
Predicted rating of Item (III) is $\frac{4}{5}*0.6+\frac{3}{5}*0.4=\frac{3.6}{5}$

Assuming people are very predictable.